# Python - Running a Python script within the main Python script, and capturing stdout?

Tags: python, stdout, sys

```
import subprocess as sub

class GUI:

    def __init__(self):
        # Redirect the stdout to self.textStream
        self.textStream = StringIO()
        sys.stdout = self.textStream

    def run(self,*args):
        sub.Popen(["python",self.filename])

    def doLogic(self):
        self.TextBox['state'] = 'normal'
        self.TextBox.insert('end',self.textStream.getvalue())
        self.TextBox['state'] = 'disabled'

G = GUI()

while True:
    G.root.update()
    G.doLogic()
```

My dilemma is that I want to be able to use the 'run' function to run another python script, and to be able to capture stdout from that script in real time and display it in my GUI. The doLogic() command is there so that I can update the GUI in real time with what's happening on the console from the other script.

What happens with this code is that the text still appears in the console window, but if I do any print() commands (In the MAIN script), they show up in my GUI as you'd expect since I redirected sys.stdout.

Currently they just spam my text box since I'm just setting it over and over again to whatevers been printed, but my main concern right now is getting the text from the stdout happening in my "sub" script.

Comment: iterate over stdout after piping

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: You need to add a runnable example, I have no idea what your code is doing as,  returning  `Popen(["python",self.filename],stdout=PIPE)` where PIPE is subprocess.PIPE will allow you to iterate over stdout but you will need to be careful or your gui will freeze

Comment: You probably want to run  use a Queue with  thread but  it completely depends on  what you are using. A runnable example as I said before would help or at least what library you are using

Comment: I edited my code to include the piping argument you listed above. I now have information showing up in my GUI, but only after the script finishes running (I have a test script that just prints a few lines, but the main one is much longer and also requires inputs). It also freezes.

Comment: You need to update as the data comes in, `for line in iter(proc.stdpout.readline,"")` do something with the line. But that will block so as I said a Queue and a Thread might be your best bet https://pymotw.com/2/Queue/